# Shakespeare: "Asses are made to bear"

Tags: meaning, ambiguity, early-modern-english, puns

When Petruchio invites Katherine to sit on his lap, she replies, "Asses are made to bear, and so are you."  (*Taming of the Shrew* Act II, Scene 1.)

The denotation is clear, donkeys (*Equus africanus asinus*) are used as beasts of burden, and "bear" loads, and Petruchio resembles a donkey.

But is Shakespeare making a Joycean pun, 300 years *avant la lettre*? Something about bare bottoms?

Comment: Well ... in *Midsummer Night's Dream*, Bottom gets turned into an ass (the donkey kind).

Comment: And we have Jane Austen, putting these words into the mouth of Mary Crawford in ‘Mansfield Park’: ‘Certainly, my home at my uncle's brought me acquainted with a circle of admirals. Of Rears, and Vices, I saw enough. Now, do not be suspecting me of a pun, I entreat.’

Comment: Katherine puns on the extended sense of *ass* = *fool*.

Comment: I wouldn't have said it was a "Joycean" pun. It's more a bawdy ["triple-entendre"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_entendre) where **ass** evokes (British) **arse** (Katherine's posterior, bum), and **bear** evokes **bare** (there's a suggestion Petruchio might be planning to get up to no good under her skirts! :)

Comment: And also something about bearing his own weight on some future occasion, and bearing children?

Comment: @Barrie England: I think there are lots of allusions. Katherine characteristically engages in "verbal sparring" with Petruchio, and I'm quite happy to assume she's suggesting he's both a bear and an ass/donkey. I think they both have a "twinkle in the eye" for each other right from the start, so maybe him bearing the weight of fatherhood if she bears him children might be in there as well (but usually, outrageous allusions to the sex act itself steer clear of bringing up that possible later "issue"! :)

Comment: Anyway, I don't want to seem mean, @Malvolio, but I think really this is Off Topic Lit Crit.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm dubious about "arse" - *OED 1* doesn't record this use/spelling before 1860. But as Barrie says, Petruchio runs with the sexual implications in "bear", "light/heavy".

Comment: @StoneyB: I'm not with you. Chaucer has plenty of references to "arse" long before Shakespeare. Are you seriously saying you don't think it would occur to anyone in Elizabethan times that *arse/bum* and *ass/donkey* are near-homophones?

Comment: @StoneyB: *OED* may nor have the earliest citation in this case. [Here](http://books.google.com/books?id=h0wJAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA3&dq=%22bare+ass%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=WRSgUI6GN_S80QHSmoD4DQ&ved=0CDcQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false) on Google books is a book from 1724 with the quote "I don't bid you be veil'd, Mrs. Pert, but there is an abundance of difference between veiling and going bare-ass'd." Clearly an instance of "ass" for "arse".

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I think StoneyB is talking about the spelling "ass" not being recorded before 1860. This is also what [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=ass&searchmode=none) says.

Comment: I believe EME was rhotic, and the vowels aren't very close: /ɑ/ vs /æ/ or /ɛ]/ (it was spelled ‘ers’ almost as often as ‘ars’). They aren't suggestively homophonic for US speakers today.

Comment: @Peter Shor: oic. Well, firstly I think Shakespeare himself wasn't big on spelling. Secondly, he mostly wrote *plays*, so the spelling wouldn't have made any difference to the audience anyway. Anyway, [here's someone else](http://muse.jhu.edu/journals/tsl/summary/v049/49.4stockton.html) who agrees with me that OED position isn't necessarily the final word. At one point he says *the word **ass** is repeatedly present, wrapped up in a web of scatological humor that puns **ass** with **arse***.

Comment: @StoneyB: I suspect they had closer vowels before the Great Vowel Shift. You can't draw any conclusions from today's pronunciations.

Comment: I can't resist throwing this one in: [Of the eleven times Sh uses 'arras', eight are accounted for by the phrase 'behind the arras' (BEHIND, buttocks).](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22times+sh+uses%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

Comment: @PeterShor   Getting closer to Sh's day, if not close. If you can push it to before the Civil War I'll concede. And if you can find *bottom* in the sense *buttocks* (*OED* gives 1794 for the earliest instance) in that period, I'll grant etymonline Bottom the Weaver.

Comment: @Malvolio: Even though I voted to close, many thanks for an interesting question!

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Spelling's relevant because it's the only evidence we've got of pronunciation. The Stockton, however, starts to convince me, though I note him hedging pretty strongly in the last paragraph of this excerpt. I'm willing to be persuaded.

Comment: @StoneyB: Surely the "arras" usages are pretty convincing. Also, Shakespeare was a great fan of Chaucer (whose every other line seemed to be about bums and arses, from what I remember of when I was a sniggering schoolboy! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers  The 'arras' usages are 'behind' because the main point of having an arras on the Elizabethan stage was for people to *hide behind* it, as in all these instances. Half of them rely on a very different gag: the monstrously fat Falstaff "hiding" behind the curtain.

Comment: @StoneyB: I hadn't thought of that. I wouldn't ordinarily contest OED, and maybe everything I think of like that can be (rightly or wrongly) shot down in flames. But I'd have thought the audience would expect plenty of "tits & bums" gags, and they'd probably be used to a bewildering variety of accents (real & feigned) so it would be natural to find them wherever you look (by which I mean, **listen**! :)